# DNS- Use Different Domain

Tags: windows, dns, ip

So I'm planning to purchase a dedicated server from Northhosts (northhosts.co.uk), and the company owner (I assume the guy runs the company, and also provides support to customers) gave me a test IP so I could test the latency of the server (it will be used as a gameserver hosting server). I noticed the domain is `william.northhosts.co.uk`, and was told that the domain of a dedicated server if I purchased one would be similar to `yourserver.client453.northhosts.co.uk`.

I know how to direct the domain on one of my sites to the server's main IP, but ingame the domain of the server is still seen as Domain as `yourserver.client453.northhosts.co.uk`. Is it possible to change the server's actual domain from `yourserver.client453.northhosts.co.uk` to something like `dawn.zyboxgaming.eu`?

I would like to offer paid gameserver hosting on my server, and it will be more professional to have the server on my own domain, and not the `yourserver.client453.northhosts.co.uk` domain.

The OS will be Windows Server 2008 R2, and it will use a 1GBPS connection using a variety of IP addresses.
I tried to take this question to Serverfault, but it got downvoted so much that I had to remove it (it got flagged as 'not relevant'), so please don't suggest that this is a Serverfault question

I tried to search for a solution to this, but I got only Linux results, and nothing for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the owner of the IP can assign a **reverse DNS** mapping. As such, this function has to be available in your server provider's control panel.

*Edit:* Oh yeah, and this change is also subject to the usual DNS propagation delays. So you may have to wait up to 48 hours until the new setting is available world-wide.

Comment: Answered well, thanks. I'll see if my provider offers this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, but I'm assuming that what you want is to attach the domain dawn.zyboxgaming.eu to your dedicated server.

First, you will need to find the IP of your dedicated server, which I assume you know. If you don't, do a DNS lookup (with `ping` or something). Next, go into the DNS settings for your domain (zyboxgaming.eu or whatever it is). Create a new A record, put in dawn.zyboxgaming.eu or whatever sub domain you want for the domain, and put in your server IP for the value. Wait up to 48 hours for the changes to take effect, and then users should be able to connect to your server by using dawn.zyboxgaming.eu, or whatever domain you specified.

If this is not the answer you want, please make your question more specific.

Comment: I already know how to do this. Example, I can get my website to resolve to my home IP address, but the DNS will still be similar to `83.43.53.34-dynamic.wavetelecom.com`. In the case of my dedicated server, both the DNS and resolve needs to be `dawn.zyboxgaming.eu`.

Comment: Why do you need the resolved address to be a specific thing? Will your users actually look into what the resolved address is? All you need is for your users to be able to access your site from your domain, right?

Comment: Also, I highly doubt that your client will do a DNS lookup for your custom domain and THEN do a reverse lookup for all other domains attached to the IP. What would the point of that be? There is no way to "un-attach" a domain that is attached to an IP if you do not own the domain. ISPs can attach whatever domain they want to your IP.

Comment: Please (carefully) read the question again. This isn't about website hosting. When they connect to the server, users can see that the DNS mapping is different and they can see the provider's name, and potentially 'rip me off' and go to my provider for gameserver hosting, instead of me.

Comment: Read the goddamn question instead of speedreading! Of cause I own 'zyboxgaming.eu', and the ISP owns 'northhosts.co.uk. Please read before you respond.

Comment: So you want to get gameserver hosting to make your own gameserver hosting business? Why did you not make that clear in your question? Also, I never said anything about hosting. Please do not speedread my answers yourself, and (carefully) read them again. In case you missed it, read here: What I said was that I highly doubt your users will go so far as to do a reverse DNS lookup on your custom hostname. So, I think you are safe.

Comment: I made this very clear in multiple parts of this question. You are still not getting this. Gameserver applications connect to their respective masterservers to get info, and the masterserver reports the real reverse-DNS domain. Users can see this DNS domain very easily.

Comment: In that case, contact your host about this. Why did you even ask here?

Comment: Because  I wanted to know whether this was possible or not.